# convert comma separated values to comma delimited values using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want convert multiple .csv file (convert comma separated values) into .csv (comma delimited values), using Python

```
import pandas as pd
Path = 'C:\\Users\\006sa\\Desktop\\Test'
Filename = '\\MB.csv'
xl = Path + Filename
df = pd.read_csv(xl, 'MB', index_col=None)
df.to_csv(Path + '\\csvfile.csv',delimiter=',')
```

I am facing this error

> to_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'delimiter'

Comment: the default sep in `to_csv` is `','` and the param is `sep` not `delimiter`

Comment: this give me comma separated value, i want comma delimited value

Comment: A `.csv` file is essentially a comma delimited txt file

Comment: @MDSAQUIBNASIRKHAN you oppose comma *separated* and *delimited* values. I have a hard time understanding what would the difference be between the two. Could you edit your question to provide a concrete example of the same data in both formats?

Comment: I suspect that this might be an X/Y problem.  Separated and delimited mean the same thing in this context, so it looks like you're trying to read a file in and then spit it right back out again.  What is it you're really trying to achieve?

Comment: i have some csv file if i edit and save them its format get changed to i wanted to save this as csv but columns should not change its format. so i came to know i have to save file as csv (comma delimited value) @FabienP

Comment: I think you should show us data you have, data you get and data you would expect instead. This way it would be easier to understand and help you.

Comment: When you say that you edit and save the file, its format gets changed.  What do you mean by this?  What are you using to edit it?  What is the format changing to?

Comment: Following link i kept 2 file - https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1x1VhRWsMmxOvomHQjNIYqihORdN3zBPC?usp=sharing

MB - actual file 
csv - after editing 

i wanted to add one column on MB.csv but whe i am saving it, format  getting changed @FabienP

Comment: I am opening one csv file adding one column  and saving it back

Answer (score 0):

The argument used in `to_csv()` is `sep`, not `delimiter`

`df.to_csv(Path + '\csvfile.csv', sep=',')`

That said, commas are the default so this argument is redundant.

Comment: They are aliases and both do the same thing.

Comment: @coldspeed Which version of pandas supports delimiter? I'm running 0.24.1 and it doesn't work.

Comment: if i am using above line i am getting output but all columns are getting mixed up

Answer (score 0):

I did some changes

```
import csv
Path = 'C:\\Users\\006sa\\Desktop\\Test'
File = '\\MB.csv'
xl = Path + File
   with open(xl, 'r') as csv_file:
     csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

       with open(Path + '\\new_file.csv', 'w',newline='') as new_file:
         csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file, delimiter=',')

       for line in csv_reader:
        csv_writer.writerow(line)
```

Its working. 
Thanks for help